# How to keep Angular 8 application state when we move from path to another

Tags: angular, angular-router

I'm working in a project and I need to keep my Angular 8 application state when the user moves from path to another.

For example: in my application I have a navbar that contains two elements. When we select an element the user is redirected to a new component (a new path). In this one for example there is a table that contains customer list (this data is getting from a backend service). When the user move on to the other path to do something else and decides to go back to see the first path (the table that contains the customer list) the data disappears. How can we keep the data or the state of each path when the user moves from path to another one.

Comment: *I'm working in a project and I need to keep my Angular 8 application state when the user moves from path to another.* you mean to another domain?

Comment: Have a read of my article on Angular state management https://medium.com/@adrianbrand/angular-state-management-with-rxcache-468a865fc3fb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to keep the app state. First point is that if you want have the fetched result in component even if the user refresh the app you should use the `Local Storage` to store your data. But if it doesn't matter actually you can create a shared `Service` and store the fetched data in an `Object` or any arbitrary data structure. When you come back to the component check the object and if it isn't `Null` display the data through that. Other ways are using `RXJS` or `NGRX`.

However if you provide some code we can help you more clearly. Let me know if there is any question here.

Good luck